# Ubuntu 16.04.1 does not recognize my Wacom Graphire3 (CTE-630)

Tags: wacom, blender

I am trying to set up a Wacom Griphire3 to work with Blender, but it won't respond to the pen or anything. The light is on, the menu displays settings, and Blender works normally with the mouse, but the Wacom won't respond. Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't be a blender issue, start without blender - does the tablet move the cursor like a mouse? Check xorg settings to get it working. See if [this page](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Xorg.conf.d) helps.

Comment: It doesn't more the cursor at all. I'll check out that link and get back to you